# PySpark: can we run a hql from a pyspark code

Tags: pyspark

I have Pyspark code which writes hql commands to a .hql file. I thought of using the subprocess library to run the hql file directly but when I do so my hql isnt running and the program is closing fine..

I know I can use sqlcontext to read each and every line from the hql and running it individually.. but I want to run the hql file from subprocess command isnt this possible???

note: i do spark-submit to run the .py code

Answer (score 0):

You can directly submit it in a shell script with spark-sql

```
$ spark-sql –master yarn-client <..other parameters for executor memory etc..> -i ./script.hql
```

spark-sql internally invokes spark-submit.

Comment: But, I wanted to trigger the hql from my python code.. if i had to use shell script i would used hive -f directly and run the hql. correct me if got you wrong..